# switching key and values for values and keys in dictionary doesn't work properly

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to count the occurances for nodes with number of neighbors from an edge list which is working except when I want to switch between keys and values, elements get lost, although it's working on other lists but this one it's not giving the entire output. what's missing?

```
[(0, 4), (1, 4), (2, 0), (3, 2), (4, 3)]
{0: 2, 4: 3, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 2}
Counter({2: 3, 3: 1, 1: 1})
{3: 2, 1: 1}  # here is wrong

 count_occurances = Counter(occurances.values())
 f = dict((v, k) for k, v in count_occurances.items())


the expected output is 
{3: 2, 1:3, 1: 1}
```

Comment: Your expected output has duplicated keys in a dictionary.  By definition, keys must be unique within a dictionary.

Comment: is there a way to fix it if I don't depend on a dictionary? or I  should keep the keys and values unswitched?

Comment: You could turn it into a list with something like `[(v, k) for k, v in count_occurances.items()]`, but without more details on _why_ you want to invert the dictionary, there's no real way to say if you should keep them as is or not.

Comment: but can I in this case have the histogram of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Counter constructor is not wrong.  When you give it a parameter that has an items method, it converts it directly to the key:count pairs (no totalling operation occurs for a dictionary):

```
D = {2: 3, 3: 1, 1: 1} 
C = Counter(D)  

# C --> Counter({2: 3, 3: 1, 1: 1})
```

To reverse the counter's values and keys, you'll need to use lists as values so that duplicate counts can store all of their keys.

```
R = dict()
R.update( (count,R.get(count,[])+[key]) for key,count in C.items() )

# R --> {3: [2], 1: [3, 1]}
```

Comment: can you please explain what you did in R.get(count,[])+[key])?

Comment: you're supposed to add Counter(D.values())

Comment: `R.get(count,[])+[key])` gets the existing list of keys for a given count and adds the new key to it. This will be used to form the tuple that will update the existing count in the R dictionary.  The first time a given count is encountered,  `R.get(count,[])` will return a new list in which to add the key.

Comment: As for `Counter(D.values())`, you example didn't indicate where `occurances` came from and the `Counter({2: 3, 3: 1, 1: 1})` result that was indicated as wrong was what I was referring to. .  In any case, the question was about inverting a dictionary so that part doesn't really matter.